# Convert SQL Query into C#

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
 s.name, count(sc.id) AS classes
FROM
 students s
 LEFT JOIN studentsclasses sc ON s.id = sc.studentid
GROUP BY s.name
HAVING count(sc.id) = 0
ORDER BY count(sc.id);
```

That query gets the count of students classes and returns the students with least classes.

How can I convert this into C#? My attempt does not yield the expected result. I have:

```
var query = (from students in ent.Students
                         join classes in ent.StudentsClasses on students.ID equals classes.StudentID into gj
                         from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new { students.Name }).ToList();
```

However that returns all the names of all the students registered in courses.

================================

Here are the tables:

```
==================
StudentsClasses  
----------------
ID (Registration ID of the class)
StudentID (ID of student taking class)
ClassID (ID of certain class)
----------------
==================

Students
---------------
ID (ID of student)
Name (Name of student)
GradeLevelID (Grade of student)
---------------
==================
```

## Final Query

```
 var query = (from students in ent.Students
                         join classes in ent.StudentsClasses on students.ID equals classes.StudentID into gj
                         from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         orderby students.StudentsClasses.Count
                         where students.StudentsClasses.Count == 0
                         select new { students.Name }).ToList();
```

Comment: This depends more on your data model than your database tables. For example if you have a navigation property on Students to Classes, it would be as simple as something like `Student.Classes.Count()` for each student - more succinctly, can you post the model classes for Student and StudentsClasses?

Comment: No need, adding `orderby students.StudentsClasses.Count` yielded the correct output. Thanks @jdphenix

Comment: That'll do it for sure. Navigation properties are a great thing - often times it not necessary to directly map a SQL query (concept for concept) i.e. , I see a join in the SQL, so I must need a join in the LINQ query - not true.  Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: fixed statement

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<Student, Student>> query = from student in ent.Students
    join studentClass in ent.StudentClasses on student.Id equals studentClass.StudentId into studentClassesJ
    from studentClass in studentClassesJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group student by student
    into studentGroup
    select studentGroup;

IEnumerable<Student> result = query.Where(x => x.Count() == query.Min(y => y.Count())).Select(x => x.Key);
```

Be aware that although you stated that your SQL query will return the students with least umber of classes, your SQL is returning only users that have no classes at all, due to `HAVING count(sc.id) = 0`.
The `LINQ` statement I provided is not filtered, but only ordered by the number of classes, but you should be able to extend it with the desired filtering.

Comment: Or, with navigation properties, `from student in ent.Students orderby student.Count() select student`

Comment: I noticed that too, I think the way to get around that would be to get the lowest count and put it into an integer, then make that a variable and put it in the query. I am having no luck so far getting that number 0 into an integer.

Comment: @JOrgus do i see this right? if the student with least classes has 3 classes, you want a query that returns all students with 3 classes?

Comment: CORRECTION: Yes, that is what I want on my original query, however, I got that working but with the WHERE clause explicitly stating the number 0. I have edited the original post so you can see the query. I wanted to make a query to get the number 0 and input it into the WHERE clause. @MichaelSander

Comment: @JOrgus edited the query hope it does what you want now